# Homestead: Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I just installed Homestead with Vagrant and Virtual-box following [Laravel 5.2 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead), when I run vagrant up command I get the error bellow.
I didn't find the config.vm file to increase time-out, but after some research I enabled intel virtualization via bios, it's not fixing it.
How I can to reveal the real problem?

```
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.
If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GUI tool for changing timeout and all. Commonly we are using Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager

add this to your Vagrantfile

`config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.gui = true
end`

Comment: I got this error when I changed the Vagrantfile file: Message: NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object

Comment: Please share your vagrant file

Comment: Please add like this `config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.gui = true
end`

Comment: Please refer this documentation https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/configuration.html
And take a look at the section `GUI VS. HEADLESS`

Comment: It works suddenly, I didn't do anything except removing the line that you gave me. I think it was a time-out problem but I'm not sure.